# Pythonでパワーポイントを作成する方法はありますか？

Tags: python, matlab, powerpoint

Pythonを用いて、パワーポイントを作成する方法についての質問です。

[【MATLAB】テンプレート使って PowerPoint スライド作成自動化：MATLAB Report Generator 編 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/eigs/items/cb48fdcd741126d09def)

MATLABのように、スライドマスターで作成したテンプレートを置換することをPythonで行いたいと考えています。
そのやり方を調べてもよくわからないため、質問させていただきました。

Comment: @cubickさん紹介ページの先にAPIがあるようです。[SlideMasters objects](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/slides.html#slidemasters-objects) そして結局要望どんぴしゃの記事は無いかもですが類似の記事。[python-pptxまとめ](https://qiita.com/pocket8137/items/3d8fda2c47664bf9130b), [Pythonを使ったレポートの自動作成【PowerPoint】【python-pptx】](https://qiita.com/kousakulog/items/34855cd8286bd4f33c08), [Pythonでパワポの説明資料（報告書）を生成する](https://qiita.com/code_440/items/22e8539da465686496d3), [excuse me how to rename the slide master by pypptx or win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60728551/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

私自身は詳しい使い方の解説まではできませんが、[python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) というそのものズバリな名前のライブラリがあるようです。

英語版 StackOverflow においても "[python-pptx]" でタグ付けされた [質問と回答が多数あります](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-pptx) 。

Answer (score 0):

[【python】Powerpoint（パワーポイント）を操作する【→業務効率UP】](https://tommysblog.net/python/python-powerpoint-control/)　の記事が参考になるのでは？

Comment: すみませんが、リンクが切れています。

Comment: @dfgujnk さん、勝手ながら修正しておきました。

Comment: スライドマスターでパワポのテンプレートを作成し、そのテンプレートを編集するプログラムのサンプルコードを探しています。